# Get specific NSOperation from NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Hi there,

In my app, I create `NSOperations` and I add them to a `NSOperationQueue`.
Sometimes, I want to cancel some specific operations from my operation queue, that's why I have defined an identifier property for my NSOperation subclass :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *identifier;
```

But when I loop into my queue's operations and I want to compare my operation's identifier to the identifier of the operation I want to fetch, I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` pointing out the if condition:

```
for (MyCustomNSOperationClass *operation in self.myOperationQueue.operations)
{
     NSString *identifier = [self getRelatedIdentifier];
     if ([operation.identifier isEqualToString:identifier])
     {
           [operation cancel];
     }
}
```

The operation's identifier should be something like `33a37fb0-8f77-0132-6c0b-5254005d9147` but when it crashes, it's something like `0x7be4af00` ( when I use `po operation.identifier` ).
I say when it crashes, because it doesn't always crash and when it doesn't crash, then the identifier is correct ( I'm not sure to be super clear... ).

As I am new with NSOperation, I wanted to know if there was an other way to achieve what I'd like to do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have an array `operations:[MyCustomNSOperationClass]` (or dictionary `operations:[String: MyCustomNSOperationClass]` ) that keeps references to all operations in the queue and then you cancel it directly without searching for it in the queue.

Comment: I just tried that, but I still have the exact same issue.

Comment: Ok finally it works when I use a dictionary. Thank you Ismail !

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was that you do not take a copy of the operation and the queue might be modified in the time of your loop.

```
  NSArray<MyCustomNSOperationClass *> *operations = operationQueue.operations.copy;

  for (MyCustomNSOperationClass *operation in operations) {

    if (!operation.isFinished && [operation.identifier isEqualToString:self.cancelIdentifier]) {
      [operation cancel];
    }

  }
```

You shouldn't rely on the state of the OperationQueue to perform your actions and storing it in a dictionary as Ismail suggested would be a viable solution.